# How to click a save as html link with changing ID's?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, extjs

I know how to click a link using javascript,

```
document.getElementById('yourLinkID').click();
```

But what if your ID is always changing or you are not sure what your ID is going to be? I have a html link that auto generate from a grid of data into a excel file that once i click on will give me a link "CLICK" and then it will save to your file. Any idea's or any other way of click a html link?

Here is an example html:

```
<a href="getyourfile..." id="myIdIsAlwaysChanging-1234">Click</a>
```

Comment: You can use classes.

Comment: the links don't have classes, it is only a href link with auto generated id's.

Comment: please add sample html code

Comment: How are you generating the html link? Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use class for that kind of button, but when you slect `$('.class-name')` it you can cause clicking on multiple links.

Other solution is to traverse DOM (ie. using jQuery)
https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

You can use this function to move between your elements:

```
$( "li" )
  .closest( "ul" )
```

Comment: So how do you know which link you should click? By beginning of the name?

Comment: I'm only going to have one click there at a time, problem is, can't use the id since the id is always changing or not sure what the id is going to be. So maybe finding it my the name string?

Comment: To click something you must find something first. You can add some custom attribute to the link and search by this attribute. Or your can search the DOM (survoc example)

Comment: Can't you just find it by the word "Click" and do a click method on that string?

Comment: You can use http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ , but it is not the best idea. You should select element by attributes, classes or id

Comment: I found it, but it's not firing a click event to it, $( "a:contains('Click')" ).click();

Comment: Can't I find the string then look in that string for the element and click it from there?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one elemement like this you can use querySelector function:

```
document.querySelector('[id^=myIdIsAlwaysChanging]').click();
```

if you have more then one element you will need to use `document.querySelectorAll` and iterate over the list.